# how to restrict multi byte character inputs like Chinese character in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, varchar

my sql table is designed to allow only varchar. 
If some Chinese characters are copy pasted to my text box and passed to db. The value is stored as "????" in table. So i need to restrict my input values only to single byte values.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "single byte values"? The set of characters that can be represented by a single byte depends on the encoding you use. Is there any reason you *want* to only use varchar?

Comment: @JonSkeet my DB architecture is to only use varchar. So I cant alter it now. By single byte value, i meant those values compatible with Varchar field without any data loss

Comment: Well that depends on which encoding you're using in your database, and what database you're using, neither of which you've told us.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using SQL server 2008 and using default encoding

Comment: "my DB architecture is to only use varchar. So I cant alter it now." - sure you can.

Comment: @shatthi: I *think* the default encoding will depend on the locale of the server you installed it on, so we *still* don't know...

Comment: Column type: varchar character_set_name: iso_1 collation_name: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score -1):

use Regex to match input.
Multi-byte character(including Chinese) matching is like this:

```
[^\x00-\xff]
```

Here is how you use it:

```
string input = "abc123#￥@%￥%&这ef是g测试hi$";

string output = Regex.Replace(input, "[^\x00-\xff]",string.Empty);

//output:abc123#@%%&efghi$

/* '￥'is a multi-byte character' */
```

Comment: That will determine if the values are in the range U+0000 to U+00FF. That doesn't necessarily correspond to single-byte values after encoding... it depends on the encoding used by the database.

Comment: Actually `[^\x00-\xff]` matches 2 byte characters only while some Chinese characters are 4 byte. A better idea is to use `IsDBCSLeadByte()`. @RhysBevilaqua